# Confirm Form Resubmission Error

Tags: php, html, browser-cache

Iam not able to understand how to handle this error even after reading a lot.

I have a main.php - which has two dropdown lists. After selecting values from any of the drop-dwon list when I click on browsers back button I can get back to main.php.
[image]

But in my second page, which feature.php -- where I go after a submitting the value from one drop-down list. In this page I have another drop-down list, where when I select a value, I get re-directed to another page. Now here when I use browsers back button I get -- Confirm Form Resubmission Error.

[image]

[image]

here after third page when I hit browsers back button I cannot go back to feature.php
how to handle this ?

Comment: It's because your second page is dependant on the values you provide in the first page. If you just go to feature.php without going through the first page it might not give any error but the dropdown in feature.php would  not contain anything. Anyways provide some code if you want more detail.

Comment: @Professor - so that means I should use caching or something to store values ?

Comment: code - [main.php](http://pastebin.com/ma8RL6U2)

and


[feature.php](http://pastebin.com/kCTVQKZM)

Comment: @Satish You could change your html form to send its data as GET parameters instead. Then you would be able to go back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem then It solved with this

```
    <?php

header('Cache-Control: no cache'); //no cache

    session_cache_limiter('must-revalidate');
?>
```

Remember to put it before 
session.start();